# Matching Negative Sequence

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match text between word1 and first occurrence of word2. What's the best way to do that, considering that text may include newline characters? Is there a pattern like this: (word1)(not word2)*(word2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lazy quantifier to match as few characters as possible between word1 and word2.

```
(word1).*?(word2)
```

See [quantifiers topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx#Greedy) on MSDN.

Comment: Better yet, use lookaround for the words.

Comment: Change the regular expression options to include the `Singleline` flag so that the `.` matches every character including new lines.

Comment: Have you actually tried that? Somehow, it doesn't work either with Multiline, Singleline or no options set.

Comment: Yes, lazy quantifiers work.  If you're trying to match the text in between words, you may need to add parens around the `.*?` part of the expression... Otherwise, it'd help to know *how* it's not working for you.

Comment: Sorry, it works. I used another application to check regexp, and Singleline didn't work there.

Answer (score 1):

You can match them using the SingleLine option:

```
//use '*' or '*?' depending on what you want for "word1 aaa word2 bbb word2"
string pattern = "word1(.*)word2";  
var m = Regex.Match(text1, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);  // the result
```

MSDN about SingleLine :

> ... causes the regular expression engine to treat the input string as if
>   it consists of a single line. It does this by changing the behavior of
>   the period (.) language element so that it matches every character,
>   instead of matching every character except for the newline character
>   \n or \u000A.

Comment: Since this is the most correct answer, I will add my comment here: There might be needing some \b to make sure that they are actually words.  Maybe the pattern should be "\bword1\b(.*?)\bword2\b"

Comment: @Casperah - possible, but the OP is not really clear about what a 'word' is.